# Kendo Grid always focus on first cell of Top Row

Tags: kendo-ui

I have checkbox in Kendo grid. Once i click on Checkbox it always focus the top cell in Kendo Grid. Below is code for Kendo grid that I am binding to checkbox value on checkbox click event in Kendo Grid

```
    $("#contactgrid").on('click', '.chkbx', function () {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            var grid = $('#contactgrid').data().kendoGrid;
            var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
            var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);
            // grid.tbody.find("tr").eq(rowIndex).foucs(); This doesn't work
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
            dataItem.set('IsSelected', checked);
    });
```

I can get the row index and cell Index in click event but I was not able to figure out to focus the specific cell. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to edit Grid with checkbox then I would suggest you to use the approach from [this code library](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/checkbox-column-and-incell-editing.aspx). No matter it uses the MVC extensions open Views/Home/Index.cshtml and see how the template is defined and the javascript used after initializing the Grid.

Here it is
Column template:

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsAdmin ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />")
            .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='masterCheckBox' onclick='checkAll(this)'/>").Width(200);


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#persons').on('click', '.chkbx', function () {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            var grid = $('#persons').data().kendoGrid;
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
            dataItem.set('IsAdmin', checked);
        })
    })

    function checkAll(ele) {
        var state = $(ele).is(':checked');
        var grid = $('#persons').data().kendoGrid;
        $.each(grid.dataSource.view(), function () {
            if (this['IsAdmin'] != state) 
                this.dirty=true;
            this['IsAdmin'] = state;
        });
        grid.refresh();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have column template that is same as you mentioned. It works perfect for batch editing and save records. Only problem I am having to focus the checkbox that was clicked. Kendo grid has scrolling bar so each time user checked the box it focus on first cell of grid.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this.  I essential refocused the cell as shown below.  There's plenty of room for improvement in the Kendo grid client-side API.  Hopefully my helper methods below will help people out.

```
var $row = getRowForDataItem(this);
var $current = getCurrentCell($row);
var currentCellIndex = $row.find(">td").index($current);

this.set('PriceFromDateTime', resultFromDate);

$row = getRowForDataItem(this);
var grid = getContainingGrid($row);

//select the previously selected cell by it's index(offset) within the td tags
if (currentCellIndex >= 0) {
    grid.current($row.find(">td").eq(currentCellIndex));
}


//Kendo grid helpers
function getColumn(grid, columnName) {
    return $.grep(grid.columns, function (item) {
        return item.field === columnName;
    })[0];
}

function getRowForDataItem(dataItem) {
    return $("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");
}

function getCurrentCell($elem) {
    return getContainingGrid($elem).current();
}

function getContainingDataItem($elem) {
    return getDataItemForRow(getContainingRow($elem));
}

function getContainingCell($elem) {
    return $elem.closest("td[role='gridcell']");
}

function getContainingRow($elem) {
    return $elem.closest("tr[role='row']");
}

function getContainingGrid($elem) {
    return $elem.closest("div[data-role='grid']").data("kendoGrid");
}

function getGridForDataItem(dataItem) {
    return getContainingGrid(getRowForDataItem(dataItem));
}

function getDataItemForRow($row, $grid) {
    if (!$grid) $grid = getContainingGrid($row);
    return $grid.dataItem($row);
}

function getMasterRow($element) {
    return $element.closest("tr.k-detail-row").prev();
}

function getChildGridForDataItem(dataItem) {
    return getRowForDataItem(dataItem).next().find("div.k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
}

function getMasterRowDataItem($element) {
    var $row = getMasterRow($element);
    return getDataItemForRow($row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zephryl. I tried your solution It was working close but it was keep focusing whatever the last checkbox clicked. Another solution i tried for this one gave unique id for each checkbox and just in my jquery function find the clicked checked box and focus it.  Below is solution that works for me.     columns.Bound(p => p.Active).Title("Active").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= Active ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' id='chk_#=Id#'/>").Width(40);                                    $(currentCheckBox).focus();

Comment: I'm guessing your event is firing before the grid updates the current cell.  Instead of var $current = getCurrentCell($row); you probably need something like you had:  $(this).closest("td").  If it's working correctly how you have it, you might try just doing $(this).closest("td").find("input").focus() and be able to avoid giving them all unique ids.  I'm assuming $(this) worked for you.  If not, try using the event details from jQuery.